# How to find equidistant hamming sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, coding-theory, binary, gray-code

Given N as the number of bits, how to find N sequences of (2^N/N) numbers each such that: given an arbitrary number n, there is always one number in each sequence that has hamming distance 1 from n.

As a reference hamming distance 1 means that two numbers have only one bit that is different.

For example given N=4, one of the possible solution to the aforementioned problem is:

```
s0 = [ 0000 0111 1000 1111 ]
s1 = [ 0001 0110 1001 1110 ]
s2 = [ 0010 0101 1010 1101 ]
s3 = [ 0011 0100 1011 1100 ]
```

If we consider for example s2 we always find a number that has hamming distance 1 from a complete sequence of numbers.

```
complete sequence   : 0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111
relative s2 numbers : 0010 0101 0010 0010 0101 0101 0010 0101 1010 1101 1010 1010 1101 1101 1010 1101
```

For N=8, one of the possible solution is as below (with decimal numbers).

```
s0 = [  0   7  25  30  42  45  51  52  75  76  82  85  97 102 120 127 255 248 230 225 213 210 204 203 180 179 173 170 158 153 135 128 ]
s1 = [  1   6  24  31  43  44  50  53  74  77  83  84  96 103 121 126 254 249 231 224 212 211 205 202 181 178 172 171 159 152 134 129 ]
s2 = [  2   5  27  28  40  47  49  54  73  78  80  87  99 100 122 125 253 250 228 227 215 208 206 201 182 177 175 168 156 155 133 130 ]
s3 = [  3   4  26  29  41  46  48  55  72  79  81  86  98 101 123 124 252 251 229 226 214 209 207 200 183 176 174 169 157 154 132 131 ]
s4 = [  8  15  17  22  34  37  59  60  67  68  90  93 105 110 112 119 247 240 238 233 221 218 196 195 188 187 165 162 150 145 143 136 ]
s5 = [  9  14  16  23  35  36  58  61  66  69  91  92 104 111 113 118 246 241 239 232 220 219 197 194 189 186 164 163 151 144 142 137 ]
s6 = [ 10  13  19  20  32  39  57  62  65  70  88  95 107 108 114 117 245 242 236 235 223 216 198 193 190 185 167 160 148 147 141 138 ]
s7 = [ 11  12  18  21  33  38  56  63  64  71  89  94 106 109 115 116 244 243 237 234 222 217 199 192 191 184 166 161 149 146 140 139 ]
```

The codes shown above have been calculated using a graph coloring algorithm, which does not scale well with the number of bits.

I am looking for an algorithm which has at most O(n^3) as time complexity, or a formula to calculate directly the sequences.

Comment: Then $N$ must be a power of $2$ since $\frac{2^N}{N}$ is an integer.

Comment: Also one observation I see is that in your example with $N = 4$, they are all generated by $\{x, x \oplus M_1, x \oplus M_2, x \oplus M_1 \oplus M_2\}$ where $M_1 = 7 = 0111_2$ and $M_2 = 8 = 1000_2$ are the bitwise masks, and $\oplus$ is xor. Might help, but I don't have time to try this currently :"

Comment: do you require the sequences to be disjoint?

Comment: I might misunderstand the meaning of disjoint, all the numbers in each sequence should not be contained in other sequences. All numbers should appear, and should appear only once. Did I answer the question?

Comment: yes, it's clear now.

Comment: @GarethMa you are correct N should be a power of 2. I did not understand the solution you suggested. What I would like to find are what you call Masks.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $N$ must be a power of $2$ so assume this.

The Hamming code [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code) is a perfect code with length $2^m-1,$ dimension $2^m-m-1,$ and minimum distance $d=3.$ Since $d=2t+1,$ this means spheres of radius $t=1$ around Hamming codewords are disjoint and every vector in $\{0,1\}^{2^m-1}$ is either a codeword or is at distance $1$ from a codeword. The number of codewords is $M=2^{2^m-m-1}.$ Let the sphere of radius $1$ centred at a word $x$ be denoted $V(x).$

*Example:* $x=000, V(x)=\{000,100,010,001\}.$

Enumerate the codewords as $c_1,\ldots,c_M$ and form an array with each row $V(c_i)$ for $i=1,\ldots,M.$

Clearly the vectors in each row are represented by $c_i$ which is at Hamming distance $\leq 1$ from them. Each $V(c_i)$ has $2^m-1+1=2^m$ entries. Since the code is perfect the union of all these $M$ disjoint lists $V(c_i)$ covers the whole space $\{0,1\}^{2^m-1}$ which numerically can be seen as well since
$$
2^{m}\times M=2^{m}\times 2^{2^m-1-m} = 2^{2^m-1}.
$$

Now append a zero to the left of each vector in $V(c_i)$ for all $i$ and call this list $V_0(c_i)$. Also append a one to the left of each vector in $V(c_i)$ for all $i$
and call this list $V_1(c_i).$

This makes no difference to the distance properties above.

Generate an array of the form
$$
\begin{array}{c}
V_0(c_1)\\
V_1(c_1)\\
 \vdots \\
V_0(c_M)\\
V_1(c_M)
\end{array}
$$
which has $2M=2^{2^m-m}$ rows. Recall $N=2^{2^m}.$ By the divisibility assumption we can now merge the rows above in groups of $2^{m}/m$ and obtain the array you want since each new row is still made up of either some Hamming codeword (with a prefix of 0 or 1) or one of its neighbours in the sphere of radius 1.

Hamming codewords can be efficiently generated by means of generating matrices.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the extensive response, which looks promising and elegant in addressing my question.

I do not clearly follow the solution. Could we work on a concrete numerical example (N=4) to evaluate such algorithm?

**Step 1**: Evaluate V(x)


`V(0) = 000 001 010 100`
`V(1) = 001 000 011 101`
`V(2) = 010 000 011 110`
`...`
`V(4) = 100 000 101 110`
`...`
`V(7) = 111 011 101 110`

Comment: **Step 2**: Evaluate V(ci) vectors.
Taken for example V(0), `c0 = 000, c1 = 001, c2 = 010, c3 = 100`.

`V(c0) = 000 001 010 100`
`V(c1) = 001 000 011 101`
`V(c2) = 010 000 011 110`
`V(c3) = 100 000 101 110`

Comment: **Step 3**: Create V0(ci) and V1(ci).

`V0(c0) = 0000 0001 0010 0100`
`V0(c1) = 0001 0000 0011 0101`
`V0(c2) = 0010 0000 0011 0110`
`V0(c3) = 0100 0000 0101 0110`
`V1(c0) = 1000 1001 1010 1100`
`V1(c1) = 1001 1000 1011 1101`
`V1(c2) = 1010 1000 1011 1110`
`V1(c3) = 1100 1000 1101 1110`

Comment: **Step 4**: Generate the final arrays.
`V0(c0) V1(c0) V0(c1) V1(c1) ... V1(c3)`
I do not compile...
I am expecting a matrix of log2(N) rows and 2^N/N columns.

Comment: @fra93, my apologies. This answer doesn't work as stated. I will try and fix it when I have more time. But I will put in a clarification below regarding your questions.

Comment: Hamming codes have distance 3, so for length 2^2-1=3 the Hamming code is the repetition code with only 2 codewords, 111 and 000. No other distance 3 code exists.

Let's repeat your example.

c0 = 000, c1 = 111

V(c0) = 000 001 010 100 
V(c1) = 111 110 101 011

V0(c0) = 0000 0001 0010 0100
V0(c1) = 1000 1001 1010 1100
V1(c0) = 0111 0110 0101 0011
V1(c1) = 1111 1110 1101 1011 . However this is a funny permutation of your answer which doesn't work as the rows stand. This is why I think there may be a way of fixing my answer.

Comment: I wrote some C code to test if the sequences work. The function generate_bases( bases ) is used to evaluate this matrix. The defines are LOGN, the number of bits, N which is 2^LOGN, and M which is 2^N/LOGN.
 https://github.com/FrancescoDellanna/equidistant_hamming_sequences/blob/main/coding_challenge.c